# Stuck in a fscanf loop

Tags: c

The point of the program is to take 2 files, one dictionary and the other is text, create an output file, and put in it all of the words in the text file, but capitalizing the words that do not exist in the dictionary.

When I run the program, it keeps asking for input, so it seems I'm stuck in a fscanf loop. And I have only 3 fscanf loops. It must be one of them, but I can't figure out which and why.

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <string.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <errno.h>
     #include <ctype.h>

     #define wosi 20
     int comp (const void *a, const void *b);

     int main(int ac, char *av[])
     {
         int wordcount,i; 
         FILE *infi, *outfi;
         char nothing, *dicptr, fina[100],letter[wosi];
         unsigned char c;
         /*to return error in case number of arguments mismatch*/
         if (ac!=3)
         {
             fprintf (stderr," prog3: Man, I need 3 arguments to work!\n");
             return (1);
         }
           /*first fscanf loop*/
         while ((fscanf(infi,"%s",&nothing)!=0))
             wordcount++;
         /* end of step 2 */
         dicptr = malloc(wordcount * wosi);
         /* end of step 3*/

         rewind(infi);
            /*second fscanf loop */
         for (i=0; fscanf(infi,"%s",&dicptr[i*wosi]) ;i++){}

         /* this is qsort stage (finishing step 4) */

         qsort (dicptr,wordcount,wosi,comp);

         /*step 5 */
         fclose (infi);
         infi = fopen(av[2],"r");

         if (infi == NULL )
         {
             perror( "opening" );
             fprintf(stderr,"Can't open %s, the file is empty\n",av[2]);
             return(1);
         }
         /*step 6 here */

         strcpy(fina, av[2]);
         strcat(fina, ".out");

         outfi = fopen(fina, "w");

         /*step 7*/
          /* third fscanf loop */
         while((fscanf(infi, "%s", letter)!= EOF));
         {
             for(i=0; letter[i]!='\0' ;i++)
             {
                 c=letter[i];
                 letter[i]= toupper(c);
             }

             if(bsearch(letter,dicptr,wordcount,wosi,comp))
             {
                 for(i=0;letter[i]!='\0';i++)
                 {
                     c=letter[i];
                     letter[i]= tolower(c);
                 }
             }

             /* fputs to print in out file*/
             for(i=0; letter[i];i++)
             {
                 fprintf(outfi,"%s",letter);
             }
         }
         free(dicptr);
         return (0);
     }

     int comp (const void *a, const void *b)
     {
         return (strcmp((const char *) a, (const char*) b));
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15440488/1758762

Comment: Any chance you could work out which loop it is by printing markers to stderr before and after each loop?

Comment: I've tried putting printing markers and the issue is still the same.

Comment: the issue was with the condition, 'while (fscanf(...) != 0).. Thank you Antoine you're awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), so I am going to give some hints only.

Firstly, I bet you didn't use the `-Wall` compiler flag for compiling:

```
h2co3-macbook:~ h2co3$ clang -Wall -o baz baz.c
baz.c:24:14: warning: variable 'wordcount' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
         wordcount++;
         ^~~~~~~~~
baz.c:12:23: note: initialize the variable 'wordcount' to silence this warning
     int wordcount,i; 
              ^
               = 0
baz.c:23:25: warning: variable 'infi' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
     while ((fscanf(infi,"%s",&nothing)!=0))
            ^~~~
baz.c:13:20: note: initialize the variable 'infi' to silence this warning
     FILE *infi, *outfi;
           ^
            = NULL
2 warnings generated.
```

Second, do you mean to compare characters or strings using the `comp()` function? If the former:

```
return *(const char *)a - *(const char *)b;
```

If the latter:

```
return strcmp(*(const char **), *(const char **)b);
```

You also appear to have some syntax errors, like the superfluous semicolon after the condition of the `while` loop.

Comment: _"You also appear to have some syntax errors, like the superfluous semicolon after the condition of the while loop."_  - Nice catch!

Comment: @SeanBright For you too :) (Wasn't it actually you who got that one earlier?)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've used the -Wall (I'm using putty)

Comment: I've removed that semicolon, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
   /*first fscanf loop*/
 while ((fscanf(infi,"%s",&nothing)!=0))
     wordcount++;
```

This loop only ends if `fscanf()` finds input that doesn't convert using `%s`. Well... basically everything will convert with `%s`, so this will read the whole file, delimited by whitespace. In the end, `fscanf()` will return `EOF`, but `EOF < 0`, so it still doesn't break your loop.  You probably wanted to compare against `EOF`:

```
   /*first fscanf loop*/
 while ((fscanf(infi,"%s",&nothing)!=EOF))
     wordcount++;
```

This does *not* address the fact that `nothing` is a `char`and will overflow.  This method is unsafe without an array and an explicit limit on the field width.  Since you don't care about storing it anyway, though, there is a special case where you can tell `fscanf()` to discard it by saying `%*s`:

```
   /*first fscanf loop*/
 while ((fscanf(infi,"%*s")!=EOF))
     wordcount++;
```